# SQL Error, possible newbie error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, odbc

I'm inserting SQL INSERT INTO statements in a VBA script using ODBC to pull data from a word doc and put it into an access database automatically.

I've verified the data isn't a mismatch and I have compared it to the other INSERT INTO statements which run without issue. These statements are linked to string variables that are then used in the cnn.execute command.

The code to store and execute my variables is as follow:

```vb
Sub TransferInstructorInfo()

'Transfer new Instructor Information record to DB

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Dim strConnection As String

Dim InstTable As String

Dim EduTable As String

Dim EmpTable As String

Dim RefTable As String

Dim strPath As String

Dim doc As Word.Document

' Define Doc Variables

 Dim Campus As String
 Dim DOE As String
 Dim Fname As String
 Etc...
'Link defined variables to forms in the word doc

Campus = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("Campus").Result & Chr(39)
DOE = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("HireDate").Result & Chr(39)
Fname = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("FirstName").Result & Chr(39)
Mname = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("MiddleName").Result & Chr(39)
Nname = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("NickName").Result & Chr(39)
etc...

InstTable = "INSERT INTO Instructors (InstructorID,[First Name],[Middle Initial],[Last Name],Nickname,Campus,[Job Title],Address,City,State,Zip,Phone,DOB,SSN,DOE)" _
& "SELECT " & InstructorID & "," & Fname & "," & Mname & "," & Lname & "," & Nname & "," & Campus & "," & Job & "," & Address & "," & City & "," & State & "," & Zip & "," & Phone & "," & DOB & "," & SSN & "," & DOE & ";" 


EmpTable = "INSERT INTO [Employment History] ( InstructorID, Company1, CompAdd1, Comp1Supervisor, CompPhone1, Comp1From, Comp1To, Comp1Title, Comp1Description, Company2, CompAdd2, Comp2Supervisor, CompPhone2, Comp2From, Comp2To, Comp2Title, Comp2Description, Company3, CompAdd3, Comp3Supervisor, CompPhone3, Comp3From, Comp3To, Comp3Title, Comp3Description, Company4, CompAdd4, Comp4Supervisor, CompPhone4, Comp4From, Comp4To, Comp4Title, Comp4Description, Company5, CompAdd5, Comp5Supervisor, CompPhone5, Comp5From, Comp5To, Comp5Title, Comp5Description, Company6, CompAdd6, Comp6Supervisor, CompPhone6, Comp6From, Comp6To, Comp6Title, Comp6Description, Company7, CompAdd7, Comp7Supervisor, CompPhone7, Comp7From, Comp7To, Comp7Title, Comp7Description )" _
& "SELECT " & InstructorID & "," & Comp1 & "," & Comp1Add & "," & Comp1sup & "," & Comp1Phone & "," & comp1from & "," & comp1To & "," & Comp1Title & "," & Comp1Desc & "," & Comp2 & "," & Comp2Add & "," & Comp2sup & "," & Comp2Phone & "," & comp2from & "," & comp2To & "," & Comp2Title & "," & Comp2Desc & "," & Comp3 & "," & Comp3Add & "," & Comp3sup & "," & Comp3Phone & "," & comp3from & "," & comp3To & "," & Comp3Title & "," & Comp3Desc & "," & Comp4 & "," & Comp4Add & "," & Comp4sup & "," & Comp4Phone & "," & comp4from & "," & comp4To & "," & Comp4Title & "," & Comp4Desc & "," & Comp5 & "," & Comp5Add & "," & Comp5sup & "," & Comp5Phone & "," & comp5from & "," & comp5To & "," & Comp5Title & "," & Comp5Desc & "," & Comp6 & "," & Comp6Add & "," & Comp6sup & "," & Comp6Phone & "," & comp6from & "," & comp6To & "," & Comp6Title & "," & Comp6Desc & "," & Comp7 & "," & Comp7Add & "," & Comp7sup & "," & Comp7Phone & "," & comp7from & "," & comp7To & "," & Comp7Title & "," & Comp7Desc & ";"


RefTable = "INSERT INTO References ( InstructorID, CharRef1, CRAddress1, CRPhone1, CharRef2, CRAddress2, CRPhone2, CharRef3, CRAddress3, CRPhone3 )" & "SELECT " & InstructorID & "," & charref1 & "," & CRAddress1 & "," & CRPhone1 & "," & charref2 & "," & CRAddress2 & "," & CRPhone2 & "," & charref3 & "," & CRAddress3 & "," & CRPhone3 & ";"

EduTable = "INSERT INTO [Education History] ( InstructorID,Sch1,Sch1Address,Sch1From,Sch1To,Sch1GradDate,Sch1DegreeType,Sch2,Sch2Address,Sch2Program,Sch2From,Sch2To,Sch2GradDate,Sch2DegreeType,TradeSchool,TSAddress,TCourse,TSFrom,TSTo,TSGradDate,TSDegreeType,[Highest Degree Earned],[Highest Awarding Institute],[ASE Certified])" _
& "SELECT " & InstructorID & "," & Sch1 & "," & Sch1Add & "," & Sch1from & "," & Sch1to & "," & Sch1Graddate & "," & Sch1Degree & "," & Sch2 & "," & Sch2Address & "," & sch2program & "," & sch2from & "," & sch2to & "," & Sch2Graddate & "," & sch2degree & "," & TSName & "," & TSAdd & "," & TSprogram & "," & TSfrom & "," & TSto & "," & TSgrad & "," & TSDegree & "," & Highestedu & "," & Highestdegree & "," & ASE & ";"

Debug.Print EduTable
Debug.Print EmpTable

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'DSN connection Set DSN locally if it fails, ODBC panel USER DSN, use access driver and point it to the database

cnn.Open "Instructor"


cnn.Execute InstTable

cnn.Execute RefTable

cnn.Execute EmpTable

cnn.Execute EduTable <----Here is where the debug breaks.
```

**The first three insert statements work** The edu table does not.

All three of these work correctly by pulling the data, here is the query that fails and I can't figure out why.

```vb
"INSERT INTO [Education History] ( InstructorID,Sch1,Sch1Address,Sch1From,Sch1To,Sch1GradDate,Sch1DegreeType,Sch2,Sch2Address,Sch2Program,Sch2From,Sch2To,Sch2GradDate,Sch2DegreeType,TradeSchool,TSAddress,TCourse,TSFrom,TSTo,TSGradDate,TSDegreeType,[Highest Degree Earned],[Highest Awarding Institute],[ASE Certified])" _
& "SELECT " & InstructorID & "," & Sch1 & "," & Sch1Add & "," & Sch1from & "," & Sch1to & "," & Sch1Graddate & "," & Sch1Degree & "," & Sch2 & "," & Sch2Address & "," & sch2program & "," & sch2from & "," & sch2to & "," & Sch2Graddate & "," & sch2degree & "," & TSName & "," & TSAdd & "," & TSprogram & "," & TSfrom & "," & TSto & "," & TSgrad & "," & TSDegree & "," & Highestedu & "," & Highestdegree & "," & ASE & ";"
```

The VBA debugger tells me it is an invalid insert statement, and the online checkers tell me it fails around [Education History], what am I'm missing here?

I do realize I can use transactions and accomplish the same thing but I believe I'd still run into an error with my INSERT INTO statements.

Any help is greatly appreciated, been stuck on this one for awhile.

Comment: Add text and date qualifiers and see if it still fails.  Better yet, parameterize the query.

Comment: I don't have values in any of the other ones. I'm using select in place of values for these queries.

 It flags the nonworking one around the start of the query.

Comment: `Debug.Print` the generated SQL and try running it in your query editor.

Comment: maybe you should add ' between parametr string

Comment: This should be fine without using values. 
@Lostidentity, I  suggest you store this whole string (concantenated) into a string variable and have that executed from that variable. This would make your debug easier to figure out. And as Tim Williams mentioned, use the Debug.Print to be able to see what's inside the string.

Comment: I've run them through the debugger, the failing one looks identical to the non-failing ones.
Everything tells me it fails at [Education History]. Here is the debugger output
INSERT INTO [Education History] ( InstructorID,Sch1,Sch1Address,Sch1From,Sch1To,Sch1GradDate,

Comment: Surround string variables with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I wasn't looking hard enough

I mistyped two variables in the Edu query.

I'd like to thank everyone for their help, specifically @Tim Williams for debug print. I noticed a few variables outputted as ,, instead of their actual entry when I followed his advice and put the output in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since your are a self-declared *newbie*, we would be remiss not to recommend for you or future readers to parameterize your SQL queries (an industry best practice) which avoids any quote enclosure, runs a bit more efficiently, and forces you as developer to explicitly define datatypes of each value (which helps avoid missing a few).

Below are both ADO and DAO methods with example for **one** query. While it may seem intimidating and too much new lines of code, still consider it as it safely bind values from your user form from Word document to keep database secure from sql injection. Some clever user of yours may try sabotaging your work! Notice id, date and string types being defined.

**ADO** Method *(which you currently use)*

```vb
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
...
Campus = doc.FormFields("Campus").Result
DOE = doc.FormFields("HireDate").Result
Fname = doc.FormFields("FirstName").Result
Mname = doc.FormFields("MiddleName").Result
Nname = doc.FormFields("NickName").Result
...

InstTable = "INSERT INTO Instructors (InstructorID, [First Name], [Middle Initial]," _
             & " [Last Name], Nickname, Campus, [Job Title]," _
             & " Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, DOB, SSN, DOE) " _
             & " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);" 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command          ' RESET CMD WITH EACH SQL QUERY 
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = InstTable
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandTimeout = 45
End With

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("InstructorIDParam", adInteger, adParamInput, InstructorID)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("FNameParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, FName)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("MNameParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, MName)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("LNameParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, LName)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("NnameParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Nname)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("CampusParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Campus)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("JobParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Job)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("AddressParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Address)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("CityParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, City)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("StateParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, State)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("ZipParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Zip)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("PhoneParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, Phone)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DOEParam", adDate, adParamInput, DOE)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("SSNParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, SSN)

cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing
```

**DAO** Method

```vb
' SET VBA reference: Microsoft Office ##.0 Access database engine object library 

Dim db As DAO.Database, qd As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Database.accdb", True)

InstTable = "PARAMETERS InstructorIDParam Long, FnameParam Text(255), MnameParam Text(255), LnameParam Text(255),"_ 
             & "         NnameParam Text(255), CampusParam Text(255), JobParam Text(255), AddressParam Text(255)," _ 
             & "         CityParam Text(255), StateParam Text(255), ZipParam Text(255), PhoneParam Text(255)," _
             & "         DOBParam Text(255), SSNParam Text(255), DOEParam DateTime;" _
             & " INSERT INTO Instructors (InstructorID, [First Name], [Middle Initial], [Last Name], Nickname," _
             & "             Campus, [Job Title], Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, DOB, SSN, DOE) " _
             & " VALUES (InstructorIDParam, FnameParam, MnameParam, LnameParam, NnameParam, CampusParam, JobParam," _ 
             & "         AddressParam, CityParam, StateParam, ZipParam, PhoneParam, DOBParam, SSNParam, DOEParam);" _

Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("", InstTable)

qd!InstructorIDParam = InstructorID
qd!FNameParam = FName
qd!MNameParam = MName
qd!LNameParam = LName
qd!NnameParam = Nname
qd!CampusParam = Campus
qd!JobParam = Job
qd!AddressParam = Address
qd!CityParam = City
qd!StateParam = State
qd!ZipParam = Zip
qd!PhoneParam = Phone
qd!DOEParam = DOE
qd!SSNParam = SSN

qd.Execute
```